# Using dropshadow filter on svg path causes it to disappear

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feDropShadow dx="2" dy="2" stdDeviation="3" flood-opacity="0.5"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <!-- Using the filter on the blue path causes it to dissapear -->
  <path d="M000,100 L300,100" stroke="blue" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>
  <!-- RENDERS FINE -->
  <path d="M000,200 L300,200" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" filter=""/>
  <!-- SHADOW WORKS ON RECTANGLE FINE -->
  <rect filter="url(#drop-shadow)" x="0" width="300" height="10" fill="green"/>
</svg>
</html>
```

Is it possible to use the drop shadow on an unclosed path element that has a stroke?

Applying the drop shadow filter seems to just make the path disappear.

I thought a path with a stroke would be rendered in a similar fashion to a `<rect>`, as shown in my example.

Am I missing something here? Or does one just need a closed  in order to use the dropshadow filter?